# How to use wildcards to allow specific domain CORS?

Tags: php, symfony, cors

I want to allows access as `allow_origin` with specified domain like this

http://anystring.fixed-name.com

here fixed-name.com  is fixed domain , but the the initial part of the domain could be anything, so I need to allow CORS anything which include at the end (fixed-name.com)

So I am trying like this

```
allow_origin: 'http://*.fixed-name.com'
```

And trying to access it using from this URL suppose http://testdomain-test.com, its throwing CORS error still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony).

You can do this directly using [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle).

Just install the package (`composer req cors`), and then in your configuration:

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    allow_origin: ['^https?://.+\.fixed-name.com$']
```

This will emit specific CORS headers for any requests that's coming from a subdomain of `fixed-name.com`, but won't emit CORS headers for any other request.

You can have an array of possible origins, and each element of the array can be a regular expression, so that will give you enough flexibility to deal with any scenario (plus, you can easily have different configurations for prod and dev using environment variables).

Comment: nelmio_cors:
   defaults:
       allow_credentials: false
       allow_origin: []
       allow_headers: []
       allow_methods: []
       expose_headers: []
       max_age: 0
       hosts: []
       origin_regex: false
       forced_allow_origin_value: ~
   paths:
       '^/api':
           allow_credentials: true
           allow_origin: ['^http?://.+\.sam.code.com$']
           allow_headers: ['*']

Comment: So I am trying to access the api using http://demo-sam.code.com , but getting CORS issue

Comment: Your regex seems to be wrong. If you are using `demo-sam.code` as domain, and the variable part is supposed to be `demo-`, then the appropriate regex would be: `.+sam.code.com`. You were adding a period (`.`) as in my example, but that was only there if you were using subdomains. Now it's only a matter of you getting the appropriate regex. The package works, is used by many thousands of users.

Comment: Be as specific or unspecific as you want. If your domain pattern is too irregular, you'll end up matching many things you are not interested on. E.g. with the above you would match `demo-sam.code.com`, but you would also match `anythingelsesam.code.com`.

Comment: If it's always going to be separated by a dash (`-`) use that in your regex: `'^https?://.+-sam.codecom$'`

Comment: Glad that it helped @Sunil. Remember that you can upvote answers that you find good and useful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. CORS wildcards are all or nothing.

Instead, test the `Origin` request header against your pattern (e.g. with a regular expression) and then echo the value back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header if it matches.

Comment: I tried reg exp:  allow_origin: ['^http?://*.+-sam.code.com$'] for origin http://demo-sam.code.com . but its not working giving cors issue whats wrong with this?

Comment: @SunilRawat — I'd imagine that whatever library you are reading that value with doesn't accept regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin , its working now . I was missing to enable reg support for my resp api packages.